# Width of a div gets ignored when content gets in

Tags: html, css

I'm new to programming. Here is the code I try to use:

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
    texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
</div>
```

So, the problem is the text won't break after `300px`. Why and how can I fix that?

Comment: Probably looking for `overflow-wrap`

Answer (score 1):

this also work

```css
div{
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
        texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for the styling of your div:

```
div{
    overflow-wrap: break-word; /* wrap/break lines that are longer the the container width */
    overflow: hidden; /* Not necessary but it will hide everything outside of the div box */
}
```

Programming is not coding and both HTML & CSS code aren't programming languages. Next time, you can just say you are new to frontend development.